# Does android broadcast any intent when application used by the user changes?

Tags: android, android-intent

I do understand (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28066231/how-to-gettopactivity-name-or-get-current-running-application-package-name-in-lo)) that we can use ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName() to get the current application running in Android; Does Android broadcast any intent when the running application changes? If not how will I know what is the current running application. Let us say at some time t1 I have x as the package name, and at time t2 this value changes, how do I update my x instead of executing ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName()?

Answer (score 1):

> I do understand (from here) that we can use ActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName() to get the current application running in Android

Not on modern versions of Android.

> Does Android broadcast any intent when the running application changes?

No.

> If not how will I know what is the current running application

Hopefully, you don't, for privacy and security reasons.

Comment: I need to know the current app that is running so that I can send a message to this app.

Comment: @savi: You have no way to "send a message" to apps that you did not write. If you want to know if your *own* apps are in the foreground, you are welcome to set up your own communications for doing that.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes you can achieve through running your app in the background, I explained the in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44427560/900128) and check [this](https://gist.github.com/rmkrishna/7e133bcf1a918a02f2c882c1d7011b18) too. I am using this and its working fine in AppLocker kind of applications.
2. You will not get any broadcast for this, you should run some loop in the background and you should find the currently running applications.